# Definition of independence for an arbitrary set of events.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space, and $\{A_i\}_{i \in I} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ an arbitrary family of events. Then we say that the events $A_i$ are independent if, for every FINITE subset $J \subseteq I$ we have that
$$P\left( \bigcap_{i \in J}A_i\right)=\prod _{i \in J}P(A_i)$$
Why are we asking for $J$ to be finite, and not an arbitrary subset of $I$? If we say only "for every subset $J \subseteq I$", we have that this new definition implies the above one (because we are including the case of $J$ finite). What about the other implication? Are the two definitions equivalent?

If they are not, can we say that
$$P\left( \bigcap_{i \in I}A_i\right)=\prod _{i \in I}P(A_i)$$
? Because it seems strange to me that can exist an infinite family of independent events that doesn't satisfy this relation.

Comment: intersection of an uncountable number of measurable sets may fail to be measurable, so it doesn't make sense to talk about its probability. (similarly, product of uncountably many terms is not well-defined in general)